# ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I run this:

```
➜  frontend git:(master) ✗ docker-compose up
Building web
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And I get the error above. This is my directory:

```
➜  frontend git:(master) ✗ ls
Dockerfile.dev     docker-compose.yml package.json       src
README.md          node_modules       public             yarn.lock
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  web: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Is it an indentation issue? I know YAML is funny about that.

This is my `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
 FROM node:alpine

 WORKDIR '/app'

 COPY package.json .
 RUN npm install

 COPY . .

 CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I am following documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context

Comment: Syntax looks right to me. Try quoting your Dockerfile name: `dockerfile: "Dockerfile.dev"` and make sure there are no other strange characters. Double check that you haven't mixed in any tabs with the spaces.

Comment: @BMitch, its not that Docker does not recognize a `Dockerfile.dev`?

Comment: the `dockerfile` section within `build` is there to build a differently named Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `Dockerfile.dev` is not recognized by Docker hence the message:

> ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

It's looking for a `Dockerfile` not a `Dockerfile.dev`.

When I tried `mv Dockerfile.dev Dockerfile` and then ran `docker-compose up`, it worked as expected.

Comment: I was able to run using your docker-compose.yml content. It might be docker version issue. This is my docker-compose version details: docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
docker-py version: 3.6.0
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018

Comment: I had this issue; updating docker fixed it for me.

Answer (score 17):

**Error**:

> ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

**Explanation:** In short, Your docker can not locate the docker file which is case sensitive, it perhaps because its not written correctly (some bad examples :`DockerFile , dockerfile, Dockerfile.txt , .DockerFile` etc...). another option might related to the file location not in the correct path.

**Solution**: 
Rename the Dockerfile (The correct spell is `Dockerfile`) an d make sure you're running it in the project location.

**For example:**

```
cd ~/<projectPath>
ls -la
#Relevant files Validation
#drwxr-xr-x  7 myUser  staff  224 Dec 18 11:38 ..
#-rw-r--r--  1 myUser  staff  312 Dec 18 11:40 Dockerfile
#-rw-r--r--  1 myUser  staff  224 Dec 18 11:38 app.py
docker build .
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you mv or copy docker-file from another location. Try just to rename it even if it's Dockerfile already

```
mv Dockerfile Dockerfile
```

Comment: Rather shockingly this was the answer I needed on my M1 Mac! Thanks, @Ilyas!